# How to select data from table selected in dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist on a page and in a dropdownlist I have names of the tables in database. 
I don't know how to insert data from the selected table in the gridview or datalist.

I tried with using the code from another c# project I did in school, but it didn't work

edit: answer added here

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
     OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter (string.Format("SELECT * from {0}", dropDownList.SelectedValue), con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
    da.Fill(ds);

    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Post it up here and we can point you in the right direction.  For future reference, you will get better results on SO if you post where you are stuck on a specific programming question instead of asking for the entire chunk of code to be written for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell the code to put the dropdowlists selected item's value in the query as follows:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection con= new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}",DropDownList1.SelectedValue), con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
    da.Fill(ds);

    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

I've tested this before posting it and it works on my machine. When you so if you can not get it worked the problem should be somewhere else.

Comment: I edited the post with a code that is checked and works on my pc, check it and let me know what came up.

Answer (score 0):

That is very easy to do. I assume your dropdownlist is in your gridview which is also a asp gridview. If this is the case then in the event you have catching the selectedindexchange or by button click. You will have to find the dropdown in the gridview and then use the selectedvalue property. It will look like this to find it(place this in your event handler)

Dim ddl as dropdownlist = gridview.row(e.rowindex).findcontrol("dropdownID")

Dim val = ddl.selectedvalue

The only changes that might have to be made in regards to finding the control is depending on what rowtype the dropdown is in and also the event being used. If the above wont find the control you can try gridview.row.findcontrol("dropdownID")

Once you get the value, you can call the method for the insert and pass it as a parameter :)

Comment: dropdownlist isn't in grid view. 


        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DataTextField="imeFIlma" 
            DataValueField="imeFIlma" 
            onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
     </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
            DataFile="~/App_Data/ASP.NET_Database(1).mdb" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [imeFIlma] FROM [filmovi]">        </asp:AccessDataSource>

this is the dropdownlist and accessdatasource from which I get the tables

Comment: If your using an asp gridview, you have access to the values of the controls within it(databound controls). If you have a control just on the form of the page then you can access the control on postback with runat=server property set. Really depends on how you have the controls setup on the page

Comment: Then in this case it's easy :). I like to let visual studio stub out the event methods for me so i would goto design view, click the ddl and goto properties, click the lightning bolt(events) and double click the selectedindexchange..it'll stub it out for you. In that event you'll have access to the selectedvalue. You can save it in a variable if you want or you can do the insert method during that event. If you save it in a variable(scope of the app) then you can set its value during the event, and pass it as a parameter for the insert method.

Comment: The post below this one is pretty much what you can do, except the select *  from {0} would be Insert Into BLAH (BLAH) values ({0},BLAH), dropdownlist1.selectedvalue)